# Why do I get a "Module parse failed" when compiling my SASS module?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, dart-sass

I'm getting the following error every time I run my CRA app, though everything runs correctly:

```
Compiling...
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/app/theme/colors.module.scss.d.ts 4:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
| 
> const colors;
| export default colors;
|

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Here's the culprit file:

```
export interface AppColors {
    background: string;
    primary: string;
    secondary: string;
}

const colors: AppColors;

export default colors;
```

It allows me to [re-use my SCSS/SASS variables in my Typescript files](https://mattferderer.com/use-sass-variables-in-typescript-and-javascript).

What's wrong?

Comment: Hey! Wanna also add your webpack config so we can see loaders and their order?

Comment: Hey! I'm using CRA, not ejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just had to replace

`const colors: AppColors;`

with

`declare const colors: AppColors;`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the content of the file with:

declare module 'AppColors' {
export interface AppColors {
background: string;
primary: string;
secondary: string;
}
export = AppColors
}

You can’t define variables in d.ts files

(sorry for not formatting code - writing from cell)